# Хранение личной информации пользователя в таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Первый вопрос. Мне в базе данных нужно хранить много личной информации о пользователе. И я задумался над таким вопросом, не стоит ли создать две таблицы: в одной хранить основную информацию (login, email, password и так далее), а во второй -дополнительную (страну, город и т.д.). Стоит ли делать такое разделение, или лучше всё хранить в одной таблице?

Второй вопрос. Я слышал, что многие рекомендуют баланс (деньги пользователя) хранить в отдельной от остальных его данных таблице. Действительно ли, так стоит делать?

Comment: Вот только пароль хранить не надо. Храните хэш

Comment: оба ответа: @Зоркий и @Dex являются правильными, ни разбивание на несколько таблиц, ни хранение в одной не являются панацеей. вы должны разобратся и четко понимать когда использовать тот или другой подход - RTFM.  
одна таблица позволит вам не писать много запросов и выдаст всю информацию о пользователе.  
с другой стороны если у вас будет больше миллиона записей и вам нужно все время работать с балансом, в то время как контактные данные задаются всего лишь раз и то при регистрации (напр). держать все в одной таблице может быть неэффективным

Comment: hashcode: мне кажется или автоподстановка URL несрабатывает для русских имен пользователей?

Comment: +1 к jmu не срабатывает =)

Answer (score 2):

Всю информацию можно хранить в одной таблице, для её отображения не придется в запросе 2 таблицы объединять, соотв. нагрузка меньше. Финансовую информацию можно вынести отдельно, особенно если с ней придется много работать, например, списывать с баланса суммы или записывать на баланс.

Comment: Спасибо, огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Чувствую, что вам необходимо прочитать о [Нормализации](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CD%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%E0%FF_%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0)

Например, у вашего пользователя может быть несколько e-mail'ов (дополнительных) или несколько адресов, а это уже отношения один-ко-многим, с которыми необходимо по-другому обходиться (и именно выносить в отдельную таблицу).

Не говоря уже о том, что люди могут жить в одинаковых странах, городах, коих у каждого может быть несколько (как и адресов), а для этого неплохо было бы иметь отдельную таблицу со странами, городами и т.п., а связывание производить в третьей таблице (разрешение отношений многие-ко-многим).

Если не думать о том, что база может разрастаться, а также о том, что ее, возможно, придется адаптировать или расширять, то можно все в одну таблицу сгружать.